# Disable Area Map Dynamically Please

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary, area

How can I **dynamically** disable an area? As a simple example, let's say I would click a specific quadrant area and that area (not the entire map) remains disabled until I click a separate button input. Would have been nice if there was a "disabled" attribute for map-area...but I know there isn't. Can anyone help me with a workaround?

```
    <img id="square_img" src="images/square.png" usemap="#square" class="chart_class">
    <map id="square_map" name="square">
        <area id="quadrant1" shape="poly"  class="area_class" coords="206,10, 300,10, 388,10, 388,100, 388,196, 300,196, 206,196, 206,100" href="#" title="Quadrant1"></area>
        <area id="quadrant2" shape="poly"  class="area_class" coords="13,10, 100,10, 194,10, 194,100, 194,196, 100,196, 13,196, 13,100" href="#" title="Quadrant 2"></area>
        <area id="quadrant3" shape="poly"  class="area_class" coords="13,208, 100,208, 194,208, 194,300, 194,387, 100,387, 13,387, 13,200" href="#" title="Quadrant 3"></area>          
        <area id="quadrant4" shape="poly"  class="area_class" coords="206,208, 300,208, 388,208, 388,300, 388,387, 300,387, 206,387, 206,300" href="#" title="Quadrant 4"></area>   
    </map>
<input type="button" value="restore"/>
```

I tried using `$(this).attr('onclick','return false;');` - that didn't work. 
I have something in mind though: have a `coords_temp` attribute with the same values as `coords`. With `$('area').click()` I'll set the `coords` to `0,0,0,0`. Should I want to enable it again, I'll use the value in `coords_temp` and set the `coords` to it. It works, but wouldn't it cause so much overhead if let's say I have a lot of map-area? And wouldn't `0,0,0,0` still be clickable? Very difficult, but it is still clickable, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would Suggest to add this once you click it 
First remove the one you do not want to have

```
function addCoord(){
    var elem = '<area id="quadrant1" shape="poly"  class="area_class" coords="206,10, 300,10, 388,10, 388,100, 388,196, 300,196, 206,196, 206,100" href="#" title="Quadrant1"></area>';
    var addElementTo = document.getElementById("square_map");
    addElementTo.innerHTML=elem;
}
```

And just add the function to your onlclick event.

Note that I took the first one as I do not know which one you want to add later.

Comment: I was hoping for a secret "disable" area that only a few people know of.xD But I guess that could work too. Ty, upvoted